# How do I retrieve the entire users profile (linkedin api)

Tags: php, api, oauth, linkedin-api

Here is my current API Query:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(firstName,lastName)
```

However this only returns the first and last name.

My scope is:

```
r_fullprofile r_contactinfo r_emailaddress
```

How do I retrieve the entire users profile?

Here is my current code:

```
        <?php
        // Change these
        define('API_KEY',      'xxx'                                          );
        define('API_SECRET',   'xxx'                                       );
        define('REDIRECT_URI', 'xxx');
        define('SCOPE',        'r_fullprofile r_contactinfo r_emailaddress');

        // You'll probably use a database
        session_name('linkedin');
        session_start();

        // OAuth 2 Control Flow
        if (isset($_GET['error'])) {
            // LinkedIn returned an error
            print $_GET['error'] . ': ' . $_GET['error_description'];
            exit;
        } elseif (isset($_GET['code'])) {
            // User authorized your application
            if ($_SESSION['state'] == $_GET['state']) {
                // Get token so you can make API calls
                getAccessToken();
            } else {
                // CSRF attack? Or did you mix up your states?
                exit;
            }
        } else { 
            if ((empty($_SESSION['expires_at'])) || (time() > $_SESSION['expires_at'])) {
                // Token has expired, clear the state
                $_SESSION = array();
            }
            if (empty($_SESSION['access_token'])) {
                // Start authorization process
                getAuthorizationCode();
            }
        }

        // Congratulations! You have a valid token. Now fetch your profile 
        $user = fetch('GET', '/v1/people/~:(firstName,lastName)');
        print_r($user);
        print "Hello $user->firstName $user->lastName.";
        exit;

        function getAuthorizationCode() {
            $params = array(
                'response_type' => 'code',
                'client_id' => API_KEY,
                'scope' => SCOPE,
                'state' => uniqid('', true), // unique long string
                'redirect_uri' => REDIRECT_URI,
            );

            // Authentication request
            $url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?' . http_build_query($params);

            // Needed to identify request when it returns to us
            $_SESSION['state'] = $params['state'];

            // Redirect user to authenticate
            header("Location: $url");
            exit;
        }

        function getAccessToken() {
            $params = array(
                'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
                'client_id' => API_KEY,
                'client_secret' => API_SECRET,
                'code' => $_GET['code'],
                'redirect_uri' => REDIRECT_URI,
            );

            // Access Token request
            $url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken?' . http_build_query($params);

            // Tell streams to make a POST request
            $context = stream_context_create(
                array('http' => 
                    array('method' => 'POST',
                    )
                )
            );

            // Retrieve access token information
            $response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

            // Native PHP object, please
            $token = json_decode($response);

            // Store access token and expiration time
            $_SESSION['access_token'] = $token->access_token; // guard this! 
            $_SESSION['expires_in']   = $token->expires_in; // relative time (in seconds)
            $_SESSION['expires_at']   = time() + $_SESSION['expires_in']; // absolute time

            return true;
        }

        function fetch($method, $resource, $body = '') {
            print $_SESSION['access_token'];

            $opts = array(
                'http'=>array(
                    'method' => $method,
                    'header' => "Authorization: Bearer " . $_SESSION['access_token'] . "\r\n" . "x-li-format: json\r\n"
                )
            );

            // Need to use HTTPS
            $url = 'https://api.linkedin.com' . $resource;

            // Append query parameters (if there are any)
            if (count($params)) { $url .= '?' . http_build_query($params); }

            // Tell streams to make a (GET, POST, PUT, or DELETE) request
            // And use OAuth 2 access token as Authorization
            $context = stream_context_create($opts);

            // Hocus Pocus
            $response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

            // Native PHP object, please
            return json_decode($response);
        }
```

Comment: if you want to get r_fullprofile from linkedin, you must to be a partner with linkedin.

Answer (score 1):

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,headline,picture-url,industry,positions,educations,last-modified-timestamp,proposal-comments,associations,interests,publications,patents,languages,skills,certifications,courses,volunteer,three-current-positions,three-past-positions,num-recommenders,recommendations-received,following,job-bookmarks,suggestions,date-of-birth,member-url-resources,related-profile-views,honors-awards,location)?format=json
```

You don't actually have to specify the members of each of the major resource attributes.

So the persons resource looks something like this:

```
Persons->id                       = string
Persons->first-name               = string
Persons->last-name                = string
Persons->headline                 = string
Persons->picture-url              = string
Persons->industry                 = array(child attributes)
Persons->positions                = array(child attributes)
Persons->educations               = array(child attributes)
Persons->last-modified-timestamp  = array(child attributes)
Persons->proposal-comments        = array(child attributes)
Persons->associations             = array(child attributes)
Persons->interests                = array(child attributes)
Persons->publications             = array(child attributes)
Persons->patents                  = array(child attributes)
Persons->languages                = array(child attributes)
Persons->skills                   = array(child attributes)
Persons->certifications           = array(child attributes)
Persons->courses                  = array(child attributes)
Persons->volunteer                = array(child attributes)
Persons->three-current-positions  = array(child attributes)
Persons->three-past-positions     = array(child attributes)
Persons->num-recommenders         = array(child attributes)
Persons->recommendations-received = array(child attributes)
Persons->following                = array(child attributes)
Persons->job-bookmarks            = array(child attributes)
Persons->suggestions              = array(child attributes)
Persons->date-of-birth            = array(child attributes)
Persons->member-url-resources     = array(child attributes)
Persons->related-profile-views    = array(child attributes)
Persons->honors-awards            = array(child attributes)
Persons->location                 = array(child attributes)
```

Answer (score 0):

You must specify all of the profile fields that you want back as part of your request.

Available profile fields are listed in the official documentation here:  https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-fields

Answer (score 0):

Replace the scope parameter from r_fullprofile to r_basicprofile. That will solve your problem. As it works for me.